# WPF designer view dont show

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have been using Visual Studio 2013 (Downloaded ISO-version) express C# winforms for some months now and i wanted to start using wpf (because of the design possibilities ), however when i start a new WPF C# project I only get MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs. i have read on many different pages about this and I've tried repairing VS and pressing CTRL + F7 while in the WPF project and many other things, but none of them works.

I can start the program without difficulty and a window which seems to be the standard window appears. and in my solution Explorer there is nothing related to the word design so i don't think its there either.

I would be grateful for any answer. :)

Comment: Also when i right click "MainWindow.xaml" and press "view Designer" nothing shows up

Comment: Not quite to understand you well, but, did you already add elements (i.e _TextBox_) in the MainWindow.xaml Window? or you're trying to _change_  designer and code windows using the _CTRL + F7 (Designer View)_ and F7 _(Code view)_ shorcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only seeing the XAML, your design view may be collapsed.  There is a small button on the bottom right of the XAML pane that allows you to collapse/uncollapse the design view.  I have included pictures, the first of which highlights the button, and the second shows the result.[image: Here is an IDE with the Design View hidden]
[image: Now we see the design view in the bottom half of the screen.]

I would encourage you though to use the design view only as a preview window, if at all.  The idea of dragging and dropping and positioning controls via the design view is very winforms style of thinking, and in WPF you want your positioning to be more relative to your layout containers.  Personally, I do not use the design view at all when I am doing wpf, as I find it becomes easy to read your markup and see it in your head.

Comment: I managed to solve it like half an hour ago, i just downloaded the other version of VS 2013 express (not the iso disc image) and then it worked, but thanks for taking your time to answer. :)